# Xamarin downloading and updating error on MacOs Sierra VM

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, macos-sierra

I have a MacOS Sierra VM on VMWare and I'am having problems to download from the Xamarin repositories.

When I first installed Xamarin on Mac, I did the manual install of all downloads from xamarin because the installer gave me an error.

I need to update to Xamarin.IOS 10.4.0 but it gives me an error on automatic installer and I cant download anything.

The manual installer on this page: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads
don't show the Xamarin.IOS 10.4.0 version that I need, the last it shows its 10.3.1

Im new on Mac Os but I have internet on my VM and I don't know what to do. 
Any ideas?

Any help is worth. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a manual installer on this url:
https://dl.xamarin.com/MonoTouch/Mac/xamarin.ios-10.4.0.123.pkg

I installed it whitout problems. I dont understand why this link isn't on: https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads
i found it by myself.

The automatic installer of updates still dont working but this resolve my problem of the Xamarin.IOS 10.4.0.123 version.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xamarin Studio for updates. Even if it fails to complete downloads, you can find all those URLs later in `~/Library/Caches/XamarinStudio-6.0/TempDownload/index.xml`.

I also have problems with automatic updates and all the links to the latest versions are almost always missing on Xamarin's Downloads page.